# SQL ,How to count rows in range

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have two table:

One is `a_tbl(uid, login_ip, login_time);`

here ip is a 32 bit integer, time is the unix timestamp.

another is `b_tbl(country, province, city, ip_from, ip_to)`

I want to find out that each range in `b_tbl` has how many unique uid in `a_tbl`.

Notice that `b_tbl` has a lot of unique rows, and `a_tbl` may exist dunplicated uid.

Thank you very much.

Comment: how are the two tables related with each other?

Comment: is there any relation exist between two tables??

Comment: I do not see any relation between these two tables! So whats the deal here?

Comment: Well, you probably need to join the table on `ip inside ip-range`, and then `count` the number of tuples `inside each ip_range`.

Comment: no relation between them. login_ip is a unsigned integer in some range [ ip_from, ip_to]

Answer (score 2):

To implement this, you can write a JOIN using BETWEEN as its predicate. That will develop the ranges; then, just count the items falling in each range. Something like this should get you started:

```
SELECT b_tbl.ip_From, b_tbl.ip_to, COUNT(a_tbl.login_ip)
  FROM a_tbl
  JOIN b_tbl ON a_tbl.login_ip BETWEEN b_tbl.ipfrom AND b_tbl.ip_to
GROUP BY  b_tbl.ip_From, b_tbl.ip_to;
```

Comment: maybe you mean `COUNT(DISTINCT a_tbl.uid)`

Comment: Until you edited it, your question didn't specify your need for uniqueness. Now that you've made it clear you want the unique IPs in each range, then COUNT(DISTINCT) is indeed required.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
SELECT ip_from
    , ip_to
    , COUNT(distinct uid) as NumberOfUniqueUserId
FROM a_tbl
INNER JOIN b_tbl on login_ip BETWEEN ip_from AND ip_to
GROUP BY ip_from
    , ip_to
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT city, count(uid)
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT A.uid, B.city
  FROM a_tbl A 
       LEFT JOIN b_tbl B 
                 ON A.login_ip >= B.ip_from AND A.login_ip <= B.ip_to
)
GROUP BY city
```

Comment: The question seems to ask for grouping by the IP range, not province.

Comment: I think each row in b_tbl represents an IP range which in turn gives the geographic location of the user. You can group by city, province, country or whatever information you have.

Comment: But you'll get different results from what he asked for. A province probably has multiple IP ranges.

Comment: makes sense, I changed it to "city"

Comment: I don't know what the networks are like where you live, but around here two people in neighboring apartments can be in different IP ranges (there are 3 different ISPs serving the town). Why not group like he said?

Comment: I somehow felt "city" would be the PK. Anyway, as long as the structure of the SQL statement is sound, OP can change it the way he/she likes.